# AWS ECS Cli vs Docker Context ECS Cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I need to deploy an application in AWS using ECS Fargate. This application has multiple services and a `docker-compose` file. I see there are two main ways to do this:

1. Using Docker's Context ECS cli, the official docs I found: [Docker doc](https://www.docker.com/blog/docker-compose-for-amazon-ecs-now-available/) and [AWS doc](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/deploy-applications-on-amazon-ecs-using-docker-compose/).
2. Using Amazon's ECS cli as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-cli-tutorial-fargate.html).

I am trying to understand the following but didn't find any comparison on the web:

- Which are the advantages/disadvantages of each way?
- Can the same result be achieved with both options, or is there something one can do that the other can't?
- What should I take in consideration when I choose one?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

So I've been trying this this past week, both approaches, and here's what I have found.

- ecs-cli and docker support different sets of tags for nontrivial features, even things such as how much CPU and memory your container needs.
- For example docker wants the deploy config in a `deploy` tag under the service. See https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/deploy/#memory
- However ECS-CLI wants things in a acs-params.yml.  There are almost no examples out there other than trivial ones though, and the ones published don't actually work with the current tooling.  What they publish doesn't work.
- Docker ECS integration works and handles tons of details for you, including VPC, subnet creation, LBs, security groups, everything.  This is an amazing part.
- ecs-cli offers tons more options than Docker CLI but you need to do a lot more work yourself, manual security group config, etc.
- I was never able to get ecs-cli to really work.  It kept choking on cpu config, and what was written in AWS docs did not actually work\
- docker compose logs doesn't work

Overall neither CLI seems to be in production shape, but docker one seems to be far ahead of where the ecs-cli is IMO.